# Проблема с массивом $_FILES

Tags: php

Всем добрый вечер столкнулся с проблемой загрузки файлов на сервер средствами PHP

Пишу код формы:

```
<form action="/finishadgalery/" method="post" enctype='mutipart/form-data' >
    <table width="700" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="6">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%" nowrap="nowrap">
                    <div class="key">
                    Название галереи:</div>
                    <input name="field_text_1" value="" id="" class="text" type="text">
                    <input type="file" name="FILE" accept="image/jpeg,image/png">
                    <input name="idpolzov" type="hidden" value="<? echo $myrow2['id']; ?>" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="20%" nowrap="nowrap">
                    <input name="" class="otprav" type="submit" value="">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Пишу код обработчика:

```
print_r($_FILES);

  if (isset($_FILES['FILE']['name'])) 
{ 
    //проверка расширения файла 
    $file_name = $_FILES['FILE']['name']; 
    $filetype = substr($file_name, strlen($file_name) - 3); 
    if ($filetype == "jpg" &&  
            $filetype == "jpeg" &&  
            $filetype == "gif" &&  
            $filetype == "bmp" &&  
            $filetype == "png") 
    {  
        // файл не должен быть пустым,  
        // или его размер должен быть <= 800000000 Кбайт 
        if($_FILES['FILE']['size'] != 0 
            AND $_FILES['FILE']['size']<=819200000)  
      { 
       //проверяем функцией is_uploaded_file 
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['FILE']['tmp_name']))  
          { 
            // проверяется перемещение файла  
            // в файловую систему хостинга 
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FILE']['tmp_name'], 
               $url."/".basename($_FILES['FILE']['name'])))  
              { 
                    // подсказываем 
                    echo 'Файл '.basename($_FILES['FILE']['name']). 
                      ' был успешно загружен в '.$url; 
              } 
          } 
       } 
    } 
}
```

Вся проблема в том что почему то после выбора файла и отправки формы массив $_FILES пустой. Права на весь сайт стоят на 777 в чем проблема представить не могу подскажите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему я вижу, а вы нет?
Тут все правильно написано?:

> enctype='mutipart/form-data'

Comment: Спасибо а то глаз совсем замылился сам не увидел

Comment: Ну бывает такое.